# Windows Phone 7 Development

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am currently developing application that does following:

1. Read Inbox (using MAPI) & SMS Interception (incoming & outgoing)
2. Read CallLog (using P/Invoke e.g. PhoneOpenCallLog) and intercept call log
3. File System Notification
4. Reading Installed Appications (using XML Provisioning)
5. Configre VPN and Email (using XML Provisioning)
6. Perform all configuration programatically that is shown in Settings menu (using Registry).

And most important, my application will always **run in background** (which is not supported in WP 7), tracking user activity.

I have read that there will not be Native code (C++) support as well as P/Invoke support in WP 7. Are there any **managed APIs** available to perform all of the above tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much completely out of luck with all of these requirements in the v1 release.

It seems like you've got something pretty specific in mind. I would recommend posting your needs on Microsoft's suggestions forum and hopefully what you want to build can be done in a release soon.

I'm sure managed api's will be how any of these functions would be delivered. With this approach whilst it has benefits, there comes the task of mapping all the platform capabilities. So there is some work to be done here.

For some apps though, this does mean not everything or unfortunately in this case, not anything, is available immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any managed APIs available to read SMS and Call Log currently?

Comment: Negative. This capability is soley reserved for the phone's owner at this point.